# Conditional .addClass()

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-tools, addclass

I cannot figure this out for the life of me. I need to have three classes given to a series of 7 tabs (based on the day of the week), .past, .today, and .future

I have the .today working wonderfully using the .getDay(), but I am having trouble assigning all the li's that come before .today to .past, and all the li's that come after .today to .future

HTML:

```
<ul class="days-of-the-week tabs clearfix">
  <li class="sunday"><span><a href="#">Sunday</a></span></li>
  <li class="monday"><span><a href="#">Monday</a></span></li>
  <li class="tuesday"><span><a href="#">Tuesday</a></span></li>
  <li class="wednesday"><span><a href="#">Wednesday</a></span></li>
  <li class="thursday"><span><a href="#">Thursday</a></span></li>
  <li class="friday"><span><a href="#">Friday</a></span></li>
  <li class="saturday"><span><a href="#">Saturday</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
// Add class .today to the correct day-of-week tab
$('ul.days-of-the-week li:eq(' + new Date().getDay() + ')').addClass('today');
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `prevAll()` to get all previous siblings of the current element, and `nextAll()` for all the following siblings.

Docs for `prevAll`: http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/

Docs for `nextAll`: http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Using these it's easy. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qYt2p/

```
var today = $('ul.days-of-the-week li:eq(' + new Date().getDay() + ')').addClass('today');
today.prevAll().addClass("past");
today.nextAll().addClass("future");​
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for netxAll and prevAll:

```
var today = $('ul.days-of-the-week li:eq(' + new Date().getDay() + ')');
today.prevAll().addClass('past');
today.addClass('today');
today.nextAll().addClass('future');
```

Comment: And there is no parenthesis in the prevAll and there is no nextAll at all on the code

Comment: Starx: because Jack is clearly faster than me at typing in his answer, there was none when I started typing. Fixed the missing parens, thanks.

Comment: No offense, but he posted 3 minutes earlier than you. So i said.

Comment: Either way, thank you both Blake and Jack! :D I didn't even know of .prevAll() or .nextAll()!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul.days-of-the-week li').each(function() {
    var c = new Date().getDay() <= $(this).index() ? new Date().getDay() == $(this).index() ? 'today' : 'future' : 'past';
    $(this).addClass(c);
});
```